# Can't log in super user created in django backend

Tags: python, django

I have the following methods to create user and super user in djagno.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False, is_active=False,
                    is_bot=False, is_mobile_verified=False, is_online=True, is_logged_in=True):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is required')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required.')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          is_active=is_active, is_bot=is_bot, is_mobile_verified=is_mobile_verified,
                          is_online=is_online, is_logged_in=is_logged_in)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        return self.create_user(email, username, password=password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, is_active=True,
                                is_bot=False, is_mobile_verified=False, is_online=True, is_logged_in=True)
```

For some reason when I create a super user on the back end I cant log in using the same email and password. This is the post method on the logs

```
POST /admin/bouncer/user/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

How can i check if my create_super_user method was called?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do a print statement in your function or check into the database to see if a new user got created.

Python2

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'New super user got created!'
```

Python3

```
print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, nothing gets logged to the console.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or 2 ?